# Save data in Android globally so it is available to all users

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions, storage, android-permissions

Is there a way to save data (somewhere globally in system) in Android 11 so that all system users can use it? I have implementation where one users gets some credentials and after that another user logs in into system. (So I have a system app that enables personalised login.) That new user should have access to the credentials from first user.
For instance, in example below, user 10 is logged in, gets some credentials from internet and saves them in Records.txt. After that comes user 15, logs in and he has access to the same file Records.txt and can take credentials from it.

I tried to do something like:

```
    public fun StoreData(data : String, activity: Activity){
        val path = activity.getExternalFilesDir(null)
        val authDirectory = File(path, "AUTH")
        Timber.d(authDirectory.toString())
        authDirectory.mkdirs()
        val file = File(authDirectory, "Records.txt")
        file.writeText("")
        file.appendText(data)
        }

    public fun GetData(activity: Activity) : String{
        //Take data from storage
        val path = "/storage/emulated/10/Android/data/com.android.testapp/files" //same path as above in path
        val authDirectory = File(path, "AUTH")
        val file = File(authDirectory, "Records.txt")
        Timber.d(authDirectory.toString())
        val data = file.readText()
        Timber.d(data)
        return data
        }
```

This leads to an error:

```
android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

I have all permissions defined as well:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="28" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
```

and additionally:

```
 android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

in application.

Did I miss something?

If someone has better idea how to solve this, please let me know!
Tnx

Comment: Users of your app? Or users of your device? Or users of something else? Where is the user logged in? What is the problem you encountered?

Comment: If you mean your application only users, you can use SharedPreferences provided by android, it is way easier  than text documents and not require any permissions.

Comment: @blackapps Sorry for not being precise enough. It is system app that enables different users to log into whole system. And problem that I encounter is described above. Actually I am not sure what is the best place to save data so everybody has access and if that is possible at all in Android 11.

Comment: @MaksimNovikov Thanks for your answer! Do SharedPreferences work when there are different system users ? I have a system app that enables personalised login into whole system.